# Storing record of 100 employees using c language

Tags: c

Using c language how we can store 100 employees record like employee name,designation,salary in variables and how we can access them.

Comment: While this is your first question, you have been a member for 2 years and 9 months! During this time why haven't you ever tried to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). By now you should also know [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Conceptually in a nutshell, you can first create an "Emp" structure(struct), with attributes such as name, salary etc... Then create an array of (100) such Emp structs.

To access it, you just loop through this array, for each struct, you can access name, salary, etc..

Hope that helps.

Comment: Glad to know it helps. If you agree, you may accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXSTR 50
#define MAXEMPLOYEES 100

typedef struct {
    char name[MAXSTR];
    char designation[MAXSTR];
    float salary;
} Employee;

typedef struct {
    Employee employeesArray[MAXEMPLOYEES];
    int count;
} Employees;

void initEmployees(Employees*);
Employee readEmployee();
void addEmployee(Employees*, Employee);
void showAllEmployees(Employees);

int main()
{
    int choice;
    Employee newEmployee;
    Employees employeesArchive;
    initEmployees(&employeesArchive);

    do{
        printf("1. Add new Employee.\n");
        printf("2. Show all Records.\n");
        printf("0. Exit.\n");
        printf("Select: ");
        scanf("%d", &choice);

        switch(choice){
        case 1:
            newEmployee = readEmployee();
            addEmployee(&employeesArchive, newEmployee);
            break;

        case 2:
            showAllEmployees(employeesArchive);
            break;
        }
     }while(choice!=0);

    return 0;
}

void initEmployees(Employees *_employees){
    _employees->count = 0;
}

Employee readEmployee(){
    Employee _newEmployee;

    printf("NEW RECORD\n");
    printf("-> Name: ");
    scanf("%s", _newEmployee.name);
    printf("-> Designation: ");
    scanf("%s", _newEmployee.designation);
    printf("-> Salary: ");
    scanf("%f", &_newEmployee.salary);

    return _newEmployee;
 }

void addEmployee(Employees *_employees, Employee _newEmployee){
    int index;
    index = _employees->count;

    strcpy(_employees->employeesArray[index].name, _newEmployee.name);
    strcpy(_employees->employeesArray[index].designation, _newEmployee.designation);
    _employees->employeesArray[index].salary = _newEmployee.salary;

    _employees->count++;
    printf("New Employee correctly added!\n");
    system("pause");
}

void showAllEmployees(Employees _employees){
    int i, allRecords;
    allRecords = _employees.count;
    for(i=0; i<allRecords; i++){
        printf("#%d\nName: %s\tDesignation: %s\tSalary: %f\n",
           i+1,
           _employees.employeesArray[i].name,
           _employees.employeesArray[i].designation,
           _employees.employeesArray[i].salary);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Better you create a linked list.

It's type of data structure in which you have to create a object which contain all information (of employee in this case) along with a *pointers* which point to other objects of list.

(Based on your question I must suggest you to Read what data structure is before moving forward..)

There are several types of data structures like single linked list ,circular linked list , double link list , tree , etc.. But here you can try most basic e.g. single link list for your requirement.

```
        #include<stdio.h>
        #include<stdlib.h>
        #define LEN=20;

        //this is our object definition
        typedef struct EMPLOYER
            {
             char name[LEN],designation[LEN];
             int salary;
             struct EMPLOYER* next_object;
            };

        void add_employer_details();
        void print_employers_details();

    EMPLOYER** main_pointer;
        char op;


    int main()
        {

           printf("shall we start storing data of employee...?(y/n)\n");
           scanf(" %c",&op);
           while(op=='y' || op=='Y')

           //to add new employee's detail
           add_employer_detail();

           //print whole database
           print_employers_detail();

        }

          void add_employer_detail()
         {
          //creating a node
          EMPLOYER *temp;

          //allocating memory
          temp=(EMPLOYER*)malloc(sizeof(EMPLOYER));
          printf("enter details of employer...\n");

          //feeling the data
          gets(temp->name);
          gets(temp->designation);
          scanf("%d",&(temp->salary));

          //making the link with other nodes
          temp->next=main_pointer;
          main_pointer=temp;

          printf("want a new entry?(y/n)");
          scanf(" %c",&op);
          }

    void print_employer_detail()
    {
       EMPLOYER* temp=*main_pointer;
       while(temp)
       {
       printf(" name of employee : %20s\n designation of employee : %20s\n salary of employee : %8d\n",temp->name,temp->designation,temp->salary);
        temp=temp->next;
        }
    }
```

Its always a good habit to allocate memory *dynamically* when it comes to data management system.But you always make sure that you are *deallocating* memory once you no longer need it to avoid memory leak. :)